# PDO execute retorna true mas não insere

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Estou tentando inserir um registro no banco utilizando esse código:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_ConteudoExtra
        (Titulo_ConteudoExtra, Texto, Id_TipoConteudoExtra, Data, Hora)
        VALUES
        ('".$nomePagina."', '".$html."','0','".$data."','".$hora."')";

  $sql = $this->db->prepare($sql);
  $execute = $sql->execute();
```

Se eu der um `var_dump` no `$execute` ele vai mostrar que o retorno foi TRUE, mas quando eu vou olhar na tabela do banco, nada foi inserido.

A primeira coisa que eu fiz, foi printar a variável `$sql` e tentar executar direto no banco pra descobrir o erro, só que não teve erro, insere com sucesso.

```
INSERT INTO tb_ConteudoExtra
            (Titulo_ConteudoExtra, Texto, Id_TipoConteudoExtra, Data, Hora)
            VALUES
            ('teste dois', '<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>teste de conteudo dentro do CKEDITOR</p>
</body>
</html>
','0','05/02/2019','15:28:36')
```

Eu tentei buscar uma solução, mas não consegui encontrar nada que me ajudou.

@EDIT
Testei assim também e continua na mesma:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tb_ConteudoExtra(Titulo_ConteudoExtra, Texto, Id_TipoConteudoExtra, Data, Hora)
            VALUES
            (':nomepagina', ':html','0',':data',':hora')";
    $sql = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(":nomepagina",$nomePagina);
    $sql->bindValue(":html",$html);
    $sql->bindValue(":data",$data);
    $sql->bindValue(":hora",$hora);
    $execute = $sql->execute();
```

Comment: Já viu se o autocommit está ligado? jogando os valores direto na query vc joga fora o beneficio da prepare query.

Comment: @rray eu testei utilizando o bindValue também, mas deu na mesma

Comment: @rray editei ali pra mostar como fiz com o bindValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algumas considerações sobre o seu código:

A) Se o campo `Data` for do tipo [date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), o formato deverá ser 'yyyy-mm-dd', que no seu caso seria: '2019-02-05' e não '05/02/2019'.

B) Testar o exemplo abaixo:

```
     $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_ConteudoExtra
            (Titulo_ConteudoExtra, Texto, Id_TipoConteudoExtra, Data, Hora)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
      $prepare = $this->db->prepare($sql);
      $array_parametros = [$nomePagina, $html, 0, $data, $hora];
      $execute = $prepare->execute($array_parametros); 
      var_dump($sql);
      var_dump($prepare);
      var_dump($array_parametros);
      var_dump($execute);
```

Qualquer problema, posta aqui quais os valores retornados pelos `var_dump`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O campo data é varchar na verdade.
Estou fazendo depois do prepare já, editei o post com o novo código utilizando o bindValue.
Obrigado!

Comment: @OtavioSouzaRocha Minha resposta resolveu o problema? Lembre-se de passar a string do SQL como parâmetro para o prepare e também para o execute.

Comment: Não resolveu ainda, continua retornando true e não inserindo

Comment: Você experimentou usar o código "C" informado em minha resposta? Tipo, copiado e colado?

Comment: Tentei agora, mas me retornou assim: Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects at most 1 parameter, 2 given[...] ......


E dessa vez o execute retornou falso

Comment: Tentei remover o $sql e deixar só os parâmetros, que é como a documentação do execute pede, mas ainda não funcionou (apesar de ter retornado true)........ Ficou assim: $execute = $prepare->execute($aray_parametros);

Comment: Veja o exemplo agora.

Comment: Retornou true, mas nada foi inserido no banco

Comment: Usa o código novo e posta o retorno de cada var_dump.